# concatenate certain columns across multiple rows

Tags: sql, grouping, rows

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
RID          SID          MID          QID          QText
------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL         NULL         NULL         10,20,30     't1','t2','t3'
10           14           13           4            'text2'
100          141          131          5,6          't5','t6'
```

I'd like to run some sql command that would basically take the row with the nulls and concatenate the QID and QText columns to each row that has a valid RID, SID, MID

so the end result would be a dataset similar to this (in this case the first row doesn't need to be there because I've concatenated the info I've got in that row to the other rows).

```
RID          SID          MID          QID          QText
------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL         NULL         NULL         10,20,30     't1','t2','t3'
10           14           13           4,10,20,30   'text2','t1','t2','t3'
100          141          131          5,6,10,20,30 't5','t6','t1','t2','t3'
```

I've tried several group_concats with different grouping but can't quite get it to work the way I need it to.  Is this transform possible with raw SQL (mysql) ?

Some of what I've tried so far (really bad attempts because I just don't know what will do what I'm trying to do) are

select group_concat(QText) from myTable group by ?  <--- I don't know of anything that I can group by that will give me what i'm looking for.  That's what I mean by really bad attempts.  I know they are wrong (group by id, qid, etc, etc).  Also thought about and tried a sum on the columns that I want to concatenate.

Comment: Can you post some of what you have attempted?

Comment: Added in some more info

Comment: Please post the exact desired result.

Comment: The second dataset I showed in the original post would be acceptable.  The only thing that I might change is returning only rows with RID that are not null.  So, basically, the second and third row of the second dataset in the original post

Answer (score 0):

If you want the NULL row(s) to be grouped with all non-NULL rows, make a copy for every group. You could, for instance, derive the list of distinct `RID, SID, MID` combinations

```
SELECT DISTINCT RID, SID, MID, QID, QText
FROM myTable
WHERE RID IS NOT NULL
   OR SID IS NOT NULL
   OR MID IS NOT NULL
```

and cross join it with the NULL row(s):

```
SELECT
  groups.RID, groups.SID, groups.MID,
  empty.QID, empty.QText
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT RID, SID, MID
  FROM myTable
  WHERE RID IS NOT NULL
     OR SID IS NOT NULL
     OR MID IS NOT NULL
) AS groups
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT QID, QText
  FROM myTable
  WHERE RID IS NULL
    AND SID IS NULL
    AND MID IS NULL
) AS empty
```

then combine the resulting set with the original set:

```
SELECT RID, SID, MID, QID, QText
FROM myTable

UNION ALL

SELECT
  groups.RID, groups.SID, groups.MID,
  empty.QID, empty.QText
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT RID, SID, MID
  FROM myTable
  WHERE RID IS NOT NULL
     OR SID IS NOT NULL
     OR MID IS NOT NULL
) AS groups
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT QID, QText
  FROM myTable
  WHERE RID IS NULL
    AND SID IS NULL
    AND MID IS NULL
) AS empty
```

Now just use the combined result set as a derived table and get your GROUP_CONCATs from it:

```
SELECT
  RID, SID, MID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(QID) AS QID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(QText) AS QText
FROM
(
  SELECT …  /* the above UNION ALL query here */
) AS s
GROUP BY
  RID, SID, MID
;
```