# Union JOIN in SQL view

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, union, sql-view

I have a situation where SQl table (A) contains data in the format of:

```
MODEL ID | PERIOD ID | VERSION | RESOURCEDRIVER | VALUE
```

The Period Field contains APRIl, MAY, JUNE etc, but also contains a value called "PERIODS" this is used in the database to signify that the row applies to all of the other periods APRIL, MAY, JUNE.

I'm trying to link the table to another which doesn't have this set up- I.E "PERIODS" does not exist. Therefore I need to create a literal entry for each of the combinations that "PERIODS" represents.

To do this I have created a SQL view (B) which lists:

```
MODEL ID| PERIOD ID | PERIOD NAME
```

This table has been filtered so that the value "PERIODS" and or any other non desirables are excluded.

I then set up a third view (C) which filters the data in TABLE A for PERIOD = "PERIODS" and created a join between TABLE A and VIEW B on MODEL ID so that for each row where the value "PERIODS" appears - multiple rows are created that replace it. This works fine for these rows but I now need to unite the result set with the original TABLE A where are literal values i.e APRIL, MAY, JUNE.

In a Query I can do this fine as I select each into a temporary table, do a `UNION` query between the two temporary tables, output the result and the drop the temp tables.

The problem here is that this is only the first part of a chain of SQL views and so I need the results to pass to the next query. (So I think maybe a store procedure could work)

My concern however is that this data could be requested by multiple users simultaneously, so can't have them all triggering temporary table creations as they would be overwriting each others data.

Can anybody tell me what the best way to achieve a union data set is in a SQL view please?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using the keyword union to join two queries?

Comment: !! I was sure I had (although had used UNION ALL) ... but I've just done it again and actually it is working ... sorry forwasting time & thanks for your response.

Comment: @serpiton How would this where statement match "APRIL" to "PERIODS"? - Surely the OR clause just matches the value  "PERIODS" in table A to the value "PERIODS" in table B

Comment: I've answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642371/concatenate-certain-columns-across-multiple-rows "concatenate certain columns across multiple rows") lately. Part of my solution involves doing what you seem to be trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT model_id, period_id, version, resourcedriver, value, NULL AS period_name FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT model_id, period_id, NULL AS version, NULL as resourcedriver, NULL as value, period_name FROM table_2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes this is the answer as Vulcronos pointed out above, I'll accept it once I've established this is the best way of doing the union. I.E if you can match PERIODS to APRIL that would be much better than having a series of queries to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the question suffer of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378): instead of asking the real question the OP is asking to fix what he has done so far.

---

This question is quite similar to the common "I want `NULL` to act as a wildcard in the query" the solution for the latter: `JOIN` on equality or `NULL`

```
a.Key = b.Key OR a.Key IS NULL
```

the first condition will check the shared value, the second condition tell the DB that, if the value in `a.Key` is `NULL`, the values in `b.Key` doesn't matter.

The only difference is that the wildcard is a specific value instead of `NULL` so the condition is changed from `IS NULL` to `= wildcard`

```
a.Key = b.Key OR a.Key = 'wildcard'
```

The query is made-up without a knowledge of the system of the OP, in the question only the base table is described, the model can be easily adapted (or if OP add information and ask I can edit it)

```
SELECT a.Model_ID, a.Period_ID PeriodA, b.Period_ID PeriodB
FROM   TableA a
       INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Model_ID = b.Model_ID
                          AND (a.Period_ID = b.Period_ID 
                            OR a.Period_ID = 'PERIODS')
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40547/1)</kbd> the demo is in T-SQL but the query uses only standard operator.